# Tutorial for Contacts-like UITableView look

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my app, I would like to create a tableview where the users can fill in their contact data. I want it to look good and I was thinking to make a clone of the Contacts app on iPhone/iPad. The problem is that I don't know how to achieve that look.
I want to find a tutorial that would explain to me how I can do it, but I couldn't find any.

Could anyone please suggest me one?

This is what I would like it to look like:

[image]